# Continuously writing data in a file

Tags: java

Good day everyone,

I'm getting the coordinates of a mouse click and wants to save it in a text file.

With this code,

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

          PrintWriter outputStream = null;
         try{
             outputStream =new PrintWriter( new FileOutputStream("stuff.txt"));
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             System.out.println("Error opening the file stuff.txt.");
             System.exit(0);
         }

         details = String.format("%s, %s", event.getX(), event.getY());

         outputStream.printf("%s, %s\n", event.getX(), event.getY());

         statusBar.setText(details);


            outputStream.close();

      }
```

I only get the first clicked coordinates.

Can you give me an idea of how to continuously record all the coordinates that I clicked?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the `FileOutputStream` in [append mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

```java
outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("stuff.txt", true));
```

Comment: Wow! you're fast! Thanks sir!